# Passing a List from one Activity to another

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, arraylist

How to pass Collections like `ArrayList`, etc from one `Activity` to another as we used to pass `Strings`, `int` with help of putExtra method of Intent?

Can anyone please help me as i want to pass a `List<String>` from one `Activity` to another?

Comment: Please do a search before posting; http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Passing+object+from+one+activity+to+another

Comment: [**Please See this Blog. This Can Help You**](http://startandroiddevelopment.blogspot.in/2013/11/how-to-pass-boolean-int-string-integer.html)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can pass an `ArrayList<E>` the same way, if the `E` type is `Serializable`.

You would call the `putExtra (String name, Serializable value)` of `Intent` to store, and `getSerializableExtra (String name)` for retrieval.

Example:

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
intent.putExtra("mylist", myList);
```

In the other Activity:

```
ArrayList<String> myList = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("mylist");
```

---

*Please note that serialization can cause performance issues: it takes time, and a lot of objects will be allocated (and thus, have to be garbage collected).*

Comment: One thing worth mentioning is, `List` interface does not extend `Serializable` so if your collection is declared by interface you have to cast it to a specific implementation first.

Answer (score 25):

First you need to create a Parcelable object class, see the example

```
public class Student implements Parcelable {

        int id;
        String name;

        public Student(int id, String name) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;

        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }


        @Override
        public int describeContents() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dest.writeInt(id);
            dest.writeString(name);
        }

        public Student(Parcel in) {
            id = in.readInt();
            name = in.readString();
        }

        public static final Parcelable.Creator<Student> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Student>() {
            public Student createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new Student(in);
            }

            public Student[] newArray(int size) {
                return new Student[size];
            }
        };
    }
```

#### And the list

```
ArrayList<Student> arraylist = new ArrayList<Student>();
```

#### Code from Calling activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelableArrayList("mylist", arraylist);
intent.putExtras(bundle);       
this.startActivity(intent);
```

#### Code on called activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);   

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    ArrayList<Student> arraylist = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("mylist");
}
```

Comment: Working like a charm, after an hour i got this, many thanks buddy.

Comment: Its better to use serializable then this one, But Its good for someone. +1

Comment: @HarishReddy Could you explain why using serializable is better? I thought  Parcelable is better than serializable for the performance.

Comment: As it works on order basis as values are given in `writeToParcel`. Is there any mechanism  to get values from `Parcel` object on  key basis?. For example  if in class we have multiple string fields  then how can we come to know which string we are getting from `Parcel` in `Student(Parcel in)` .

Comment: @HarishReddy: Using Serializable allows for a simpler implementation, but using Parcelable provides better performance. Which one is better depends on the circumstances: if the performance Serializable provides in your use case is adequate, then you should prefer the simpler approach. But if using Serializable is too slow in your use case, you should try using Parcelable instead.

Comment: @Shahin ShamS Could you please have a look at this question. I tried to implement your solution there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68050680/how-to-display-data-from-one-activitys-recyclerview-to-another-activitys-recyc

Answer (score 5):

use `putExtra` to pass value to an intent. use `getSerializableExtra` method to retrieve the data
like this

Activity A :

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

intent.putExtra("arraylist", list);
startActivity(intent);
```

Activity B:

```
ArrayList<String> list = getIntent().getSerializableExtra("arraylist");
```

Comment: Hi RajaReddy, I pass array list A activity to B activity. B activity i have changed one value and come back to A activity value not changing. Please help me

Comment: While coming back to B Activity you have to pass data From B to A.. or make that array as global array and update from B activity .

Comment: In my case i have option to go C activity. In that scenario how can i update the arraylist?

Comment: Then make it as Global in Application class... and update and use where ever you want to use

Comment: Thanks for your tips. If possible give me ur mail id, I will ask doubts through email.

Answer (score 5):

I tried all the proposed techniques but none of them worked and stopped my app from working and then I finally succedded. Here is how I did it...
In main activity I did this:

```
            List<String> myList...;
            Intent intent = new Intent...;
            Bundle b=new Bundle();
            b.putStringArrayList("KEY",(ArrayList<String>)myList);            
            intent_deviceList.putExtras(b);
            ....startActivity(intent);
```

To get the data in the new Activity:

```
    List<String> myList...
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (b != null) {
        myList = bundle.getStringArrayList("KEY");
    }
```

I hope this will help someone...

Answer (score 1):

To pass ArrayList from one activity to another activity, one should include

```
intent.putStringArrayListExtra(KEY, list); //where list is ArrayList which you want to pass
```

before starting the activity.And to get the ArrayList in another activity include

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            temp = bundle.getStringArrayList(KEY); // declare temp as ArrayList
                }
```

you will be able to pass ArrayList through this.Hope this will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Use of ViewModel is better fix than Serializable or Parcelable