# how to convert arraylist to string

Tags: android

im follow this post to pass arraylist as parameter to another screen from here [Passing a List from one Activity to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340776/passing-a-list-from-one-activity-to-another)  now i want to save arraylist in string after get what do i do???

String myvalue;
             Activity A :

```
 ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();


   intent.putExtra("arraylist", list);
   startActivity(intent);

   Activity B:

 ArrayList<String> list = getIntent().getSerializableExtra("arraylist");



        how to save list in  myvalue;
        like   myvalue=list;
```

Comment: how do you want to save the arraylist in string?

Comment: in my arraylist only single value how doi pass arraylist as parameter to another activity and convert to string again

Comment: in my code  ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();  have only single value i want to pass as parameter to another activity and show in textview

Comment: ArrayList<String> list = (ArrayList<String>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("arraylist");
String s = list.get(0); You want this?

Comment: George ur code save arraylist value to String myvalue?????

Comment: yes in my arraylist have only single value

Comment: If your list has only one parameter why you do not pass string instead of list?

Comment: how/ how to pass? how topass inintent single value of list?

Comment: check this line intent.putExtra("arraylist", list); how to pass only single value of list here???

Comment: please check this lin ein my code  intent.putExtra("arraylist", list); is take whole arraylist as parameter i want to just pass araylistposition[0] value as parameter and get in string how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YOUR_CLASS.class);
intent.putExtra("string", list.get(0));
startActivity(intent);
```

in your another activity:

```java
String str = getIntent().getStringExtra("string");
```

Answer (score 0):

In FirstActivity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, target.class);
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("name", stringarraysdb);
startActivity(intent);
```

In secondActivity:

```
Intent i=getIntent();
ArrayList ringarraysdb=i.getIntegerArrayListExtra("name");
```