# How to pass ArrayList<CustomeObject> from one activity to another?

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle, serializable

I want to send Following ArrayList from one activity to another please help.

```
ContactBean m_objUserDetails = new ContactBean();
ArrayList<ContactBean> ContactLis = new ArrayList<ContactBean>();
```

I am sending the above arraylist after adding data in it as follows

```
  Intent i = new Intent(this,DisplayContact.class);
  i.putExtra("Contact_list", ContactLis);
  startActivity(i);
```

But I am getting problem while recovering it.

```
ArrayList<ContactBean> l1 = new ArrayList<ContactBean>();
Bundle wrapedReceivedList = getIntent().getExtras();
l1= wrapedReceivedList.getCharSequenceArrayList("Contact_list");
```

At this point I am getting this error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<CharSequence> to ArrayList<ContactBean>
```

My ContactBean class implements Serializable please also tell why we have to implement serializable interface.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15790499/passing-arraylist-of-objects-between-activities

Comment: make your custom Object Parcelable.

Comment: Accepted answer copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/11340842/

Answer (score 31):

**In First activity:**

```
ArrayList<ContactBean> fileList = new ArrayList<ContactBean>();
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, secondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("FILES_TO_SEND", fileList);
startActivity(intent);
```

**In receiver activity:**

```
ArrayList<ContactBean> filelist =  (ArrayList<ContactBean>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("FILES_TO_SEND");`
```

Comment: it does not seem to working ,  my app is keep crashing

Answer (score 15):

you need **implements Parcelable** in your `ContactBean` class, I put one example for you:

```
public class ContactClass implements Parcelable {

private String id;
private String photo;
private String firstname;
private String lastname;

public ContactClass()
{

}

private ContactClass(Parcel in) {
    firstname = in.readString();
    lastname = in.readString();
    photo = in.readString();
    id = in.readString();

}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

    dest.writeString(firstname);
    dest.writeString(lastname);
    dest.writeString(photo);
    dest.writeString(id);

}

 public static final Parcelable.Creator<ContactClass> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<ContactClass>() {
        public ContactClass createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new ContactClass(in);
        }

        public ContactClass[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ContactClass[size];

        }
    };

   // all get , set method 
 }
```

and this get and set for your code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,DisplayContact.class);
intent.putExtra("Contact_list", ContactLis);
startActivity(intent);
```

second class:

```
ArrayList<ContactClass> myList = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("Contact_list");
```

Comment: I am sure you meant: `ArrayList<ContactClass> myList` instead of `ArrayList<String> myList`

Comment: yes you right @gunar thanks for help

Comment: I have never used Parcelable. but as I have come to know Parcelable  is 10 times faster than serializable, will look forward to use parcelable. I have getter setter methods in my ContactBean class which I simply use to store data in class variables after making its object and then I am adding that object to ArrayList<ContactBean>. is this possible if the class is parcelable.

Comment: sorry, i don't get your mean, but if i want tell you simple, you need both above method and getter and setter method.i edit my class

Comment: ok thanks. Will definitely try it out.

Comment: @VarunKarhadkar yes is possible , if is not possible then why we use that? sorry i'm busy first time don't get your mean.

Comment: @Dev i need see your code, because this code working fine, if you can't fix problem answer new question and notify me

Comment: in second activity how to i set value in textview ? @ShayanPourvatan

Comment: @MohammadAli what is your mean? set it as normally, you've got your object, now you can set it with `setText` method with your property that you need.

Comment: ok i'll use this code **`ArrayList<Pojo> myList = new ArrayList<Pojo>();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(), SubCategoryData.class);
            intent.putExtra("SubCategory",myList);

            startActivity(intent);`** but `myList` size is **0** @ShayanPourvatan

Comment: this is not related to this post, you can ask another question.

Answer (score 5):

Use this code to pass `arraylist<customobj>` to anthother **Activity**

firstly serialize our contact bean

```
public class ContactBean implements Serializable {
      //do intialization here
}
```

Now pass your arraylist

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this,name of activity.class);
 contactBean=(ConactBean)_arraylist.get(position);
 intent.putExtra("contactBeanObj",conactBean);
 _activity.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: how to i set value in textView ??

Comment: which value????

Comment: `aaraylist` in next activity

Comment: are u wanna set whole arraylist data to textview ?

Comment: no some fields..