# AsyncTask in SplashScreen

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask

I have made an application which uses json to download data from server and displays it in a ListView by following [this tutorial.](http://www.wingnity.com/blog/android-json-parsing-and-image-loading-tutorial/)
But now I want to do this process in the SplashScreen while loading and then send all the downloaded data to MainActivity. How can a achieve this.
Thank You.

**My MainActivity**

```
package tutorial.json.com.jsonparsingtutorial;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.ParseException;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ArrayList<Actors> actorsList;

ActorAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    actorsList = new ArrayList<Actors>();
    new JSONAsyncTask().execute("http://microblogging.wingnity.com/JSONParsingTutorial/jsonActors");

    ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new ActorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, actorsList);

    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), actorsList.get(position).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}


public class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {


    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {

            //------------------>>
            HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            // StatusLine stat = response.getStatusLine();
            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if (status == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);


                JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
                JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("actors");

                for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    Actors actor = new Actors();

                    actor.setName(object.getString("name"));
                    actor.setDescription(object.getString("description"));
                    actor.setDob(object.getString("dob"));
                    actor.setCountry(object.getString("country"));
                    actor.setHeight(object.getString("height"));
                    actor.setSpouse(object.getString("spouse"));
                    actor.setChildren(object.getString("children"));
                    actor.setImage(object.getString("image"));

                    actorsList.add(actor);
                }
                return true;
            }

            //------------------>>

        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        if(result == false)
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
}
```

**Actor Adapter**

```
package tutorial.json.com.jsonparsingtutorial;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ActorAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Actors> {
ArrayList<Actors> actorList;
LayoutInflater vi;
int Resource;
ViewHolder holder;

public ActorAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Actors> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    vi = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    Resource = resource;
    actorList = objects;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // convert view = design
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        v = vi.inflate(Resource, null);
        holder.imageview = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
        holder.tvName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        holder.tvDescription = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvDescriptionn);
        holder.tvDOB = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvDateOfBirth);
        holder.tvCountry = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvCountry);
        holder.tvHeight = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvHeight);
        holder.tvSpouse = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvSpouse);
        holder.tvChildren = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvChildren);
        v.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }
    holder.imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    new DownloadImageTask(holder.imageview).execute(actorList.get(position).getImage());
    holder.tvName.setText(actorList.get(position).getName());
    holder.tvDescription.setText(actorList.get(position).getDescription());
    holder.tvDOB.setText("B'day: " + actorList.get(position).getDob());
    holder.tvCountry.setText(actorList.get(position).getCountry());
    holder.tvHeight.setText("Height: " + actorList.get(position).getHeight());
    holder.tvSpouse.setText("Spouse: " + actorList.get(position).getSpouse());
    holder.tvChildren.setText("Children: " + actorList.get(position).getChildren());
    return v;

}

static class ViewHolder {
    public ImageView imageview;
    public TextView tvName;
    public TextView tvDescription;
    public TextView tvDOB;
    public TextView tvCountry;
    public TextView tvHeight;
    public TextView tvSpouse;
    public TextView tvChildren;

}

private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }

}
}
```

**Actor class**

```
package tutorial.json.com.jsonparsingtutorial;

public class Actors {

private String name;
private String description;
private String dob;
private String country;
private String height;
private String spouse;
private String children;
private String image;

public Actors() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public Actors(String name, String description, String dob, String country,
              String height, String spouse, String children, String image) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.dob = dob;
    this.country = country;
    this.height = height;
    this.spouse = spouse;
    this.children = children;
    this.image = image;
}


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getDob() {
    return dob;
}

public void setDob(String dob) {
    this.dob = dob;
}

public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}

public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}

public String getHeight() {
    return height;
}

public void setHeight(String height) {
    this.height = height;
}

public String getSpouse() {
    return spouse;
}

public void setSpouse(String spouse) {
    this.spouse = spouse;
}

public String getChildren() {
    return children;
}

public void setChildren(String children) {
    this.children = children;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

}
```

Comment: Well you can pass ArrayList using intent http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21250339/how-to-pass-arraylistcustomeobject-from-one-activity-to-another

Comment: tried it but app is crashing. It would be of great help if you could show what to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create SplashScrenActivity and download the data using JSONAsyncTask and once you get the response, In onPost you have to start  MainActivity and send the downloaded data to MainActivity. While JSONAsyncTask is executing you can show ProgressBar in onPreExecute and hide ProgressBar in onPostExecute.

To Send data to MainActivity, you need to make your Actor Class implement Parcelable Interface. Once Actor Class implements Parcelable, This is how you can send data, from SplashScreenActivity to MainActivty -

In SplashScreenActivity,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this,MainActivty.class);
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("ActorsList", actorsArrayList);
startActivity(intent);
```

In MainActivty onCreate() you get ActorsList using,

```
if (getIntent().hasExtra("ActorsList")) {

            ArrayList<Actors> actorsList =
                    getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("ActorsList");
}
```

This will be your Parcelable implemented class,

```
public class Actors implements Parcelable {

    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String dob;
    private String country;
    private String height;
    private String spouse;
    private String children;
    private String image;

    public Actors() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Actors(String name, String description, String dob, String country,
                  String height, String spouse, String children, String image) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.dob = dob;
        this.country = country;
        this.height = height;
        this.spouse = spouse;
        this.children = children;
        this.image = image;
    }


    protected Actors(Parcel in) {
        name = in.readString();
        description = in.readString();
        dob = in.readString();
        country = in.readString();
        height = in.readString();
        spouse = in.readString();
        children = in.readString();
        image = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Creator<Actors> CREATOR = new Creator<Actors>() {
        @Override
        public Actors createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Actors(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Actors[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Actors[size];
        }
    };

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(String dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(String height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public String getSpouse() {
        return spouse;
    }

    public void setSpouse(String spouse) {
        this.spouse = spouse;
    }

    public String getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren(String children) {
        this.children = children;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        parcel.writeString(name);
        parcel.writeString(description);
        parcel.writeString(dob);
        parcel.writeString(country);
        parcel.writeString(height);
        parcel.writeString(spouse);
        parcel.writeString(children);
        parcel.writeString(image);
    }
}
```

and in onPostExecute you just need to start MainActivity like below,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("ActorsList", actorsArrayList);
startActivity(intent);
```

For more information on how to make class parcelable please refer the link below - 
[How can I make my custom objects Parcelable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181526/how-can-i-make-my-custom-objects-parcelable)

Comment: can u please tell me how to implement Parcelable Interface in the Actor Class

Comment: ok i have one problem when i am running this program it is working perfectly but the images are changing until the correct image is loaded can u pls suggest me a fix

Comment: 'images are changing' , can you elaborate bit

Comment: a sort of flickering
i mean for example:
image of position

Comment: ...image at position 4 must have that pic dirctly instead here pic at posi 1 then 2 then 3 and then finally 4 appears but when the original app is being started no such flickering happens

Comment: Basically for downloading Image you have written, DownloadImageTask. Instead of that you can use standard Image downloading libraries like Picasso, Glide(from Google) for downloading images. They handle Image downloading and rendering smoothly. For more details please refer link below - https://github.com/bumptech/glide