# Passing Object returns null in acitivity intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, bundle

I am trying to send data from activity to other via intent. Sending **String** or **integer** work perfectly fine. But when I add **Parecelable** object in same intent ,it always return **null** for **Strings** , *Integers* and **Object**. Below is my code for setting data to intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.putExtra("SomeText", "sometext");
intent.putExtra("itemId", itemId);
intent.putExtra("someuser",user);

startActivity(intent);
```

And in other activity I am getting values as:

```
String som = getIntent().getStringExtra("SomeText");
int itemird = getIntent().getIntExtra("itemId", 0);
User user = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("someuser");
```

I also have tried different other solutions as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-an-object-from-one-activity-to-another-on-android) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906925/how-do-i-pass-an-object-from-one-activity-to-another-on-android)

Can anybody here suggest me what my mistake is or any better solution?

So this is my Parcelable class

```
public class User implements Parcelable{
    private int mData;
    private String username;
    private String imagePath;
    private String userId;

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void setImagePath(String imagePath) {
        this.imagePath = imagePath;
    }

    public String getImagePath() {
        return imagePath;

    }

    public User() {

    }

    public User(String username, String userId) {
        this.username = username;
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    public User(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<User> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<User>() {
        public User createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new User(in);
        }

        public User[] newArray(int size) {
            return new User[size];
        }
    };

    private User(Parcel in) {
        mData = in.readInt();
    }

}
```

Comment: You can make your Custom Java Object implement Serializable and use putExtra. If it didn't work , paste error logs.

Comment: It's probably an issue with the implementation of the parcelable interface methods in your User class. Can you post these methods here?

Comment: you must persist all property in `writeToParcel` and read all of them in constructor `User(Parcel in)` see this link to get better my mean http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21250339/how-to-pass-arraylistcustomeobject-from-one-activity-to-another/21250450#21250450

Answer (score 0):

Carefully read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2141166/6950238) answer of [Jeremy Logan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/76835/jeremy-logan). You should:

1) implement `Parcelable` for Your `User` class;

2) class cast for Your `User` class like `User user = (User) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("someuser")` and `intent.putExtra("someuser", (Parcelable)user)`.

Comment: My User object is a Parcelable object.

Comment: So check `public static final Parcelable.Creator` method.

Answer (score 0):

Pass object like this structure

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putParcelable("someuser",user);
Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.putExtra("SomeText", "sometext");
intent.putExtra("itemId", itemId);
intent.putExtra(b);
startActivity(intent);
```

then received like this

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
if(b != null) {
User user = b.getParcelable("someuser");   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Parcelable class

```
    public class User implements Parcelable{

        String name;


        @Override
        public int describeContents() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        /**
        * Storing the User data to Parcel object
        **/
        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
            dest.writeString(name);


        }

        /**
        * A constructor that initializes the User object
        **/
        public User(String uName){
            this.name = uName;

        }

        /**
        * Retrieving User data from Parcel object
        * This constructor is invoked by the method createFromParcel(Parcel source) of
        * the object CREATOR
        **/
        private Student(Parcel in){
            this.mSName = in.readString();

        }

        public static final Parcelable.Creator<User> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<User>() {

            @Override
            public User createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
                return new User(source);
            }

            @Override
            public User[] newArray(int size) {
                return new User[size];
            }
        };
    }

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       mBtnOk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    // Creating an instance of Student class with user input data
                    User userObj= new User ("Name");

                    // Creating an intent to open the activity 
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class);

                    // Passing data as a parecelable object to 
                    intent.putExtra("user",userObj);

                    // Opening the activity
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });



    }

    }





    public class NextActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_next);

     // Fetching data from a parcelable object passed from MainActivity
            User user= getIntent().getParcelableExtra("user");



    }

    }
```

Comment: @SairaNawaz  check your class in your  writeToParcel() method


            dest.writeString(name); add this line in your code for name and id.!

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution with change your `User` class like below ans it works:

```
public class User implements Parcelable {
private int mData;
private String username;
private String imagePath;
private String userId;

public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public void setImagePath(String imagePath) {
    this.imagePath = imagePath;
}

public String getImagePath() {
    return imagePath;

}

public User() {
}

public User(String username, String userId) {
    this.username = username;
    this.userId = userId;
}
public User(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

    dest.writeInt(mData);
    dest.writeString(username);
    dest.writeString(imagePath);
    dest.writeString(userId);
}

private void readFromParcel(Parcel in ) {

    mData     = in .readInt();
    username  = in .readString();
    imagePath = in .readString();
    userId    = in .readString();
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<User> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<User>() {
    public User createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new User(in);
    }

    public User[] newArray(int size) {
        return new User[size];
    }
};

    private User(Parcel in) {
        readFromParcel( in );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't implement your user model class properly.
You can try this

```
public class User implements Parcelable {

private int mData;
private String username;
private String imagePath;
private String userId;

public User(String username, String userId) {
    this.username = username;
    this.userId = userId;
}
public User(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
public User() {} // empty constructor

public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public void setImagePath(String imagePath) {
    this.imagePath = imagePath;
}

public String getImagePath() {
    return imagePath;

}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

    dest.writeInt(mData);
    dest.writeString(username);
    dest.writeString(imagePath);
    dest.writeString(userId);
}

private User(Parcel in) {
    mData     = in.readInt();
    username  = in.readString();
    imagePath = in.readString();
    userId    = in.readString();.
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<User> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<User>() {
    public User createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new User(in);
    }

    public User[] newArray(int size) {
        return new User[size];
    }
};
```

}

Then in your Splash activity, you can do this. I'm assuming you have created a user object to want to send to MainActivity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.putExtra("someuser",user); // using the (String name, Parcelable value) overload! 
intent.putExtra("SomeText", "sometext");
intent.putExtra("itemId", itemId);
intent.putExtra(bundle);

startActivity(intent);
```

You can then receive it in MainActivity like this

```
User user = (User) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("someuser");
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi why you use parcelable if **serializable** is easy to use and easy to understand and implement

implement serializable in your class

```
public class Place implements Serializable {
        private int id;
        private String name;

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
```

Then you can pass this object in intent

```
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondAct.class);
     intent.putExtra("PLACE", Place);
     startActivity();
```

in the second activity you can get data like this

```
 Place place= (Place) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("PLACE");
```

parcelable  is used when there is large data need to send other wise you can use **serializable**

**Let me know if not work**

Comment: inner class also need to be serialized

Comment: send me your class

Comment: It didn't work because apparently it's intended behaviour... https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=216581

Answer (score 0):

I tried all solutions but no one mentioned this solution, the writeToParcel() is problematic. The parcel should be written and read in the same order.