# IndexOutOfBounds Exception on ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have a class with parameterized constructor and ArrayList as a parameter. The size of ArrayList is valid on constructor but on the `onCreate` method size is zero. How it's possible?

```
    public class ViewDetail extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "val";
    final String POSITION_CLICKED="position";


    private ArrayList<DataModel> mData=new ArrayList<>();
    private Context mC;
    public ViewDetail( Context c,ArrayList<DataModel> data) {
        this.mData = data;
        this.mC = c;
        Log.v(TAG,"MDATA SIZE "+mData.size());
    }
     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_detail);
    Log.v(TAG,"MDATA SIZE2 "+ mData.size());
        short pos = 0;
        try {
            pos = getIntent().getExtras().getShort(POSITION_CLICKED);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}}
```

Comment: I hope you are trying to pass an array list from one activity to another. Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21250339/how-to-pass-arraylistcustomeobject-from-one-activity-to-another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  public ViewDetail( Context c,ArrayList<DataModel> data) {
        this.mData = data;
        this.mC = c;
        Log.v(TAG,"MDATA SIZE "+mData.size());
    }
```

Wrong !!...Don't create constructor of that class which extends the `Activity`.

> Instead of above you can pass that data via `Intent`