# how to send the array by using an intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

how to send the array in intent in android studio?

i have two array list

```
Eve_id[];//here i had stored 5 diffrent values.
sc_id[];//here i had stored 5 diffrent values.
```

now i have to send these two array to next activity,i have used the code like this

1st activity`

```
Intent k = new Intent(context, Receiver.class);
              k.putExtra("Event_id", Eve_id);
              k.putExtra("schedule_id", sc_id);`
```

2nd activity

```
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        long[] event_id = extras.getLongArray("Event_id");
        int[] schedule_id = extras.getIntArray("schedule_ids");
```

i dont know weather it is correct are not ,but  i am not able to receive any data!
any one can suggest how to solve this!

Comment: Check with it -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21250339/how-to-pass-arraylistcustomeobject-from-one-activity-to-another

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Bundle` for That

```
 Intent passArray = new Intent(MainActivity.this ,YourSecondClass.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putStringArray("my_array", array);
    startActivity(passArray , bundle);
    passArray.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(passArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ArrayList` instead of array:

```
ArrayList<Long> eventIds = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> scheduleIds = new ArrayList<>();
```

fill them and put into *bundle*:

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putIntegerArrayList("schedule_ids",scheduleIds);
extrass.putLongArrayList("Event_id", eventIds);

Intent k = new Intent(context, Receiver.class);
k.putExtras(extras);
```

and then extract this values in `Receiver` activity:

```
Bundle extras  = getIntent().getExtras();
ArrayList<Long> eventIds = extras.getLongArrayList("Event_id");
ArrayList<Integer> scheduleIds = extras.getIntegerArrayList("schedule_ids");
```