# How to get data value of ArrayList to another activity

Tags: android

Hey I have an arraylist in activity1.class I want to get data from that array to show the data episodeList.size() in activity2.class here my list code

```
public class EpisodeAdapter  extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<EpisodeAdapter.EpisodeHolder>{
    private List<Episode> episodeList;
    public EpisodeAdapter(List<Episode> episodeList) {
        this.episodeList = episodeList;
    }
    @Override
    public EpisodeHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_episode , null);
        EpisodeAdapter.EpisodeHolder mh = new EpisodeAdapter.EpisodeHolder(v);
        return mh;
    }

public int getItemCount() {
        return episodeList.size();
    }
```

Comment: You can send that list with intent or you can store it in local database or strings.xml to access it from anywhere

Comment: send ArrayList with Parseable and then send it with bundle.putParceableArrayList(key, list).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass ArrayList<CustomeObject> from one activity to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21250339/how-to-pass-arraylistcustomeobject-from-one-activity-to-another)

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, className);
            intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("episodeList", episodeList);
            startActivity(intent);
```

and you can get it by

```
ArrayList<Episodes> list=getIntent.getparcelableArrayList("episodeList")
```

and don't forget to make the model class to parcelable

Comment: `and don't forget to make the model class to parcelable` please add this part to your question to make it complete

Comment: just implement like this...class Episode implement Parcelable

Answer (score 0):

You can use intents to pass values from one activity to another activity like this:
In your current activity from where you want to pass ArrayList:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, TargetActivity.class);
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("key", your_array_list);
startActivity();
```

And in your Activity where you want to receive the values:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();  
ArrayList arrayList= intent.getStringArrayListExtra("key");
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem on my project. I just used SharedPreferences. It's like a local file in your project, but you cannot see it. You simply put the values inside and retrieve them in your 2nd Activity.

For more information: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences

Answer (score 0):

> Implement Parcelable in your ArrayList model.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ServiceDetailActivity.class);
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("key", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) arrayList);
startActivity(intent);
```

> And get list in another activity

```
arrayList = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("key");
```