# How to display data of cardview in another activity

Tags: android, android-cardview

I have recycler view in my fragment activity and I am displaying data in card view in main activity. how can I navigate data of card view to another activity.
in fragment class I have recycle rview and in main activity I am calling recycle rview adapter

Comment: if you don't have DB, you can put information from **CardView** to **Intent**

Comment: if you have the data in arrayList you can use this list with intent to pass your data to any activity. Read this post carefully.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340776/passing-a-list-from-one-activity-to-another

Comment: @Alexander I have used DB

Comment: @sapanravani I think you can send the ID of item (not position in list) to activity. And then do query by id from DB and fill details activity.