# how to pass diffrent strings array to the same listview

Tags: android

Hello guys I have created a listview on second activity and I have three button on main activity .on click of each button it will display a listview with diffrent names in second activity. I dont how to pass a string array through intent and display in a listview.

MAIN ACTIVITY

```
String []str={"hello","world"};
String []str2={"display","text"};
String [] str3={"android","programming"};

Intet intent=new Intent  (this,Second activity. class);
intent.putExtra("stringA",how to pass the string array here)
startActivity  (intent);
```

Comment: You should probably add some Codesnippets or further explanations. Currently the answer would be like "As a parameter".

Comment: This will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11340842/5110536

Answer (score 1):

```
String []str={"hello","world"};
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putStringArray("key", str);
Intent i = new Intent(context, YourActivity.Class);
i.putExtras(b);
```

then to get from your second activity

```
Bundle data = this.getIntent().getExtras();
String[] array = data.getStringArray("key");
```

Answer (score 0):

On MainActivity Button Click
   you call this

```
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
bundle.putStringArray(key, new String[]{value1, value2});
Intent i=new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.Class);
i.putExtras(bundle);
```

to read in SecondActivity
  call this.

```
Bundle bundle=this.getIntent().getExtras();
String[] array=bundle.getStringArray(key);
```