# How to pass ArrayList data to another onboarding adapter activity in android?

Tags: java, android

I want data of arraylist   ,List  songs = new ArrayList<>();    , on my SlideAdapter.  I have two addapter one is "Adapter.java" and second one is "SliderAdapert.java" I want to use List  songs = new ArrayList<>(); on both adapter

```
   private void fetchSongs() {

    //define list to carry songs
    List<ModelClass> songs = new ArrayList<>();
    Uri songLibraryUri;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        songLibraryUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL);
    } else {
        songLibraryUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    }

    //projection
    String[] projection = new String[]{
            MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_MODIFIED,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA
    };

    //sort order
    String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED + " DESC" ;

    //Querying
    try (Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(songLibraryUri, projection, null, null, sortOrder)) {

        // cache the cursor indices
        int idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
        int nameColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
        int dateColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_MODIFIED);
        int pathColimn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);


        //getting the values
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            // get values of colums for a give audio files
            long id = cursor.getLong(idColumn);
            String name = cursor.getString(nameColumn);
            long date = cursor.getLong(dateColumn);
            String path = cursor.getString(pathColimn);


            //song uri
            Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id);

            //album art uri
            // Uri albumartUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart"),alb)

            //remove .mp3 extension on song's name
            name = name.substring(0, name.lastIndexOf("."));

                // song item
                ModelClass song = new ModelClass(path, name, uri, date);
            // add song to songs list
            songs.add(song);

        }



        //show songs on rv
        showSongs(songs);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Number of Songs:" +songs.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


}

private void showSongs(List<ModelClass> songs) {

   // songs.clear();

    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    layoutManager.setOrientation(RecyclerView.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    adapter = new Adapter(songs);


    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
   // adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

I want List < ModalClass> songs = new ArrayList<>(); on my SlideAdapter.java

```
   public class SlideAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

Context context;
LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
RelativeLayout relativeLayout1, relativeLayout2;

public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";
public static final String Name = "nameKey";
public static final String Phone = "phoneKey";
public static final String Email = "emailKey";
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

public SlideAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;

}

//Array
public int[] slide_images = {
        R.drawable.intro_call,
        R.drawable.intro_call4,
        R.drawable.intro_call4
};

public String[] slide_heading = {

        "Please allow auto call recording on your device to get better experience",
        "Please make a dummy call",
        "Is this is your recorded dummy call ?"
};

public String[] slide_btn = {

        "I Got it, Continue",
        "Please Make a dummy call",
        "No"
};

public String[] slide_des = {

        "",
        "It helps us to take accurate location of your recorded calls",
        ""
};


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return slide_heading.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {

    return view == (RelativeLayout) object;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {


    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.intro_item_layout, container, false);


    TextView head = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.introtext);
    TextView head2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.introtext2);
    TextView des = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.introdesc);
    TextView recHead = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.recText);
    TextView recTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.recTime);
    TextView recSource = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.recSource);
    ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.introImg);
    Button btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.introB);
    Button noB = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.noB);
    Button yesB = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.yesB);

    ImageView playB = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.play);
    ImageView pauseB = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.pause);

    relativeLayout1 = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.relative1);
    relativeLayout2 = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.relativ2);

    relativeLayout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    relativeLayout2.setVisibility(View.GONE);


    img.setImageResource(slide_images[position]);
    head.setText(slide_heading[position]);
    des.setText(slide_des[position]);
    btn.setText(slide_btn[position]);


    if (position == 1) {

        sharedpreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String n = "ed1.getText().toString()";
                String ph = "ed2.getText().toString()";
                String e = "ed3.getText().toString()";

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

                editor.putString(Name, n);
                editor.putString(Phone, ph);
                editor.putString(Email, e);
                editor.commit();

                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"));//change the number
                context.startActivity(callIntent);
            }
        });
    }

    if (position == 2) {
        relativeLayout2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        relativeLayout1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
       
         // I want the data of the List <ModalClass> songs = new ArrayList<>();  
      // here                  

    }
    container.addView(view);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    //container.removeView(container);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

Comment: Check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340776/passing-a-list-from-one-activity-to-another

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'getIntent' in 'SlideAdapter'  . This is show in SlideAdapter.java

Comment: getIntent in method of activity we cannot use it in Adapter.

Comment: Add getIntent in your activity in which your `SlideAdapter.java` is present.

Comment: How can i pass the arraylist from activity to SliderAdapter.java

Comment: You can pass list in constructor of SlideAdapter.